# Center loading indicator at the bottom of LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

I have implemented pagination in my app using jetpack compose. You can find full code here in case you need more details : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose

Here is my code :

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(COLUMN_COUNT),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            end = Dimens.GridSpacing,
            bottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(LocalDensity.current)
                .toDp().dp.plus(
                    Dimens.GridSpacing
                )
        ),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
            Dimens.GridSpacing,
            Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ),
        content = {

            items(lazyTMDbItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val tmdbItem = lazyTMDbItems[index]
                tmdbItem?.let {
                    TMDbItemContent(
                        it,
                        Modifier
                            .height(320.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                        onClick
                    )
                }
            }

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                when (loadState.append) {
                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        item(span = span) {
                            LoadingRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing))
                        }
                    }
                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val message =
                            (loadState.append as? LoadState.Error)?.error?.message ?: return@apply

                        item(span = span) {
                            ErrorScreen(
                                message = message,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing),
                                refresh = { retry() })
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        })
```

As you see I set columns as a fix size :

```
columns = GridCells.Fixed(COLUMN_COUNT)
```

And in order to set loading indicator and error view at the bottom of Grid in the middle of screen, I have :

```
private val span: (LazyGridItemSpanScope) -> GridItemSpan = { GridItemSpan(COLUMN_COUNT) }
```

So when I use it as bellow using `span` for `items`, it will be centered :

```
item(span = span) {
      LoadingRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = Dimens.GridSpacing))
}
```

My question is when columns is not a fix size. So we have :

```
columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 120.dp)
```

How can I center loading indicator and error view at the bottom of Grid in the screen? since as I understand `span` is working with a fix size.

Comment: Were you using a `CircularProgressIndicator`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`LazyGridItemSpanScope.maxLineSpan`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/LazyGridItemSpanScope#maxLineSpan()) value.

As reported in the doc:

> The max line span (horizontal for vertical grids) an item can occupy. This will be the number of columns in vertical grids or the number of rows in horizontal grids.
>
> For example if `LazyVerticalGrid` has 3 columns this value will be 3 for each cell.

```
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 30.dp),
    ) {

        items(
            listgrid,
            span = { index ->
                GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
            }
        ) {
             //...
        }
    }
```

[image]